# How to do conditional rspec code based on tags

Tags: ruby, rspec, stripe-payments, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Is there a way add an if statement around:

```
  invalid_customer = RuntimeError.new("error code")
  StripeMock.prepare_error(invalid_customer, :create_source)
```

based on if the live_only or live tag is not called?

I would live to eliminate the live and mock tests and only have one since it's redundant.

#### Result

```
rspec spec --tag live_only => would not run the above StripeMock code
rspec spec => would run the mock code
```

#### Rspec

```
it "should raise error when invalid customer (Live Version)", live_only: true do
  err = "error code"
  expect {
    payment_gateway.add_source(customer_id: "invalid-id", source_id_or_token: default_card_token)
  }.to raise_error(RuntimeError) {|e|
    expect(e.message).to eql err
  }
end

it "should raise error when invalid customer (Mock Version)", live: false do
  invalid_customer = RuntimeError.new("error code")
  StripeMock.prepare_error(invalid_customer, :create_source)
  
  expect {
    payment_gateway.add_source(customer_id: "invalid-id", source_id_or_token: default_card_token)
  }.to raise_error(RuntimeError) {|e|
    expect(e.message).to eql "error code"
  }
end
```

#### Updated

I found a way to set a variable @running_mock, see answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to set a variable @running_mock.

```
  config.before(:example) do
    @running_mock ||= (config.filter_manager.inclusions.rules.to_hash.keys & [:live,:live_only]).blank?
  end
```

RSpec

```
it "should raise error when invalid customer (Live & Mock Version)", live: true do
  if @running_mock
    invalid_customer = RuntimeError.new("error code")
    StripeMock.prepare_error(invalid_customer, :create_source)
  end

  expect {
    payment_gateway.add_source(customer_id: "invalid-id", source_id_or_token: default_card_token)
  }.to raise_error(RuntimeError) {|e|
    expect(e.message).to eql "error code"
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The tags are stored in rspec `metadata`, as [documented in rspec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/metadata/user-defined-metadata).

You can access and branch on them, if you really want:

```rb
example.metadata[:live_only]
```

Comment: An rspec `it` clause is an "rspec example". The things you've been adding inside the "rspec `describe`/`context`" blocks are called "rspec examples". Take a look at the docs I linked, there are code examples there already.

Comment: However, does the metadata change based on the --tag passed while running rspec? or is it a constant value based on the tag on the block?   I need something to tell me if --tag live_only is passed when rspec is run.

Comment: Oh, not sure if there's a particular "rspec" way to retrieve what rspec has parsed from input, but you should always be able to inspect `ARGV` yourself and handle accordingly. Does that help?